# Brownie Smart Contract Function how to understand parameters

Tags: solidity, brownie

From the smark contract to get WETH from ETH on this link
https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xccb14936c2e000ed8393a571d15a2672537838ad#writeContract

To make the deposit function work I have to code it like
`weth.deposit({"from": account, "value": 0.02 * 10 ** 18})` and the withdraw function like `weth.withdraw(0.02 * 10 ** 18,{"from": account})`
I don't understand the logic of the difference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the deposit function you need to send your ethereum in a transaction, in the withdraw one you call the withdraw function with the amount parameter. They will do the transfer to you. (If you used the same call as the first one you would send your ethers to the contract)